# What is the fastest way to maintain a large set of expressions?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, performance-tuning, data-structures

In my algorithm I need to maintain a set (an unordered list of distinct elements) of expressions supporting two operations:

- Test an expression for membership in the set
- Adding a new expression to the set

Expressions are to be compared using `SameQ`. The set can have hundreds of thousands of elements and I want it to work as fast as possible. In most programming languages I would use a hash-table or a balanced tree to implement such a set. Is there any better data structure in *Mathematica* for this purpose than a plain `List`? Is it worth trying to manually implement a better structure?

Comment: Try linked lists.

Comment: You can use a hash table implicit in `DownValues`, just by introducing some symbol (say, `presentQ`). Starting definition is `presentQ[_]=False`. Then,adding is as simple as `presentQ[expr] = True`, and `presentQ` itself tests for membership. This seems the easiest option. You can also use ``System`Utilities`HashTable`` as an alternative.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Using downvalues is a simple and great idea! I should have realized this myself.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov This is a standard and most common way to implement this sort of things. Sometimes one can also use `SubValues`, although the difference is mostly syntactic. But I have not seen a clear exposition in the documentation which would have explained that hash table functionality in Mathematica is most easily achieved via `DownValues`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I implemented the approach you suggested, but later found a bug in my implementation: when `expr` is a pattern, the plain `presentQ[expr] = True` does not have the intended meaning. The fix is to use `presentQ[Verbatim[expr]] = True` instead.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Yes, sure. This is well-known to me. It just did not cross my mind that you could have patterns among your expressions, this is rather untypical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)'s comment:

> You can use a hash table implicit in `DownValues`, just by introducing
>   some symbol (say, `presentQ`). Starting definition is `presentQ[_] = False`.
>   Then, adding is as simple as `presentQ[expr] = True`, and `presentQ` itself
>   tests for membership. This seems the easiest option. You can also use
>   `` System`Utilities`HashTable `` as an alternative.

However, [Vladimir](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7288/vladimir-reshetnikov) notes:

> When `expr` is a pattern, the plain `presentQ[expr] = True` does not have the intended meaning. The fix is to use `presentQ[Verbatim[expr]] = True` instead.

I would also add that the new `Association` data structure in *Mathematica* 10 is likely to be a faster and perhaps more convenient approach than using either downvalues or the `` System`Utilities`HashTable ``.

Comment: How would `Association` be used?  The list in `Association` has to be in the form of `lhs -> rhs`.